# Using pytest for Hardware in Loop Testing

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, pytest, python-asyncio

I would like to use pytest for Hardware in Loop Testing.

Basically, with Python and Pytest hardware functionalities are going to be asserted.

My problem is with the structural implementation of the tests:
I would like every tests to be separate (so they can be tested individually), but also that they can be used in a pipeline manner. Example:

```
class TestCamera:
    def test_camera_start():
        pass

    def test_photo_captured():
        pass
```

and

```
class TestAudio:
    # And so on
```

Everything works fine. But now imagine I want to implement a system test with a runtime. I however want to use the old tests functions that I have written and use them in a pipeline manner. For example:

```
# system_test.py
while phone_is_booted:
   user_input = get_user_input_over_simulated_screen()
   # Now pass over user input to a list of input testers that run all sequencialy and async in tasks or threads.
```

Are there any frameworks for something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to write separate tests? If one test depends on another one, you really only have one test.

Comment: Maybe [`pytest-order`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) can help. But it seems like a misuse to use python **unit testing** tools for hardware. Maybe [RobotFramwork](https://robotframework.org/) is the better choice?

Comment: Thanks. I decided to write the tests into different objects and link them together